# print all elements in array which have specific string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have this struct :

```
struct MapsData {
    var company = String()
    var city    = String()
    var mark   = String()
    var latitude:  Double
    var longitude: Double
}
var places = [
    MapsData(company: "Tireshop", city: "Berlin", mark: "market", latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.03121860),
    MapsData(company: "Ginza", city: "Tokio", mark: "restaurant", latitude: 37.331831, longitude: -122.031862),
    MapsData(company: "McOz", city: "London", mark: "restaurant", latitude: 37.331831, longitude: -122.031862)
]
```

How to print all elements which have `mark: "restaurant"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for el in places {
    if el.mark == "restaurant" {
        print(el.city, el.company, el.latitude, el.longitude, el.mark)
    }
}
```

Comment: `for place in places where place.mark == "restaurant" {`

Comment: The `for ... in ... where ...` variant seems a little cleaner and more concise. Where clauses can be really useful in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter to get all elements with `mark` set to "restaurant"

```
print(places.filter({$0.mark == "restaurant"}))
```